# ssl facebook error: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

Tags: ssl

this is my problem, 
i've installed my ssl certificate on my website in order to use it in my facebook app.
entering the site in https mode is working fine, perfectly, so i create my facebook app, but when i try to install in the canvas i receive this message:

ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

so i think my ssl doesn't work fine with facebook, i'm wondering what type of ssl certificate i need to make my app workin fine.
there is no list of facebook talking about the kind of ssl, anybody can give me more info about this problem?
thak's in advance to all the people that will suggest me something

Comment: I just ran into this myself, on a second app I've built. The first works perfectly fine, I have a feeling it's related to the hosting server.